# Browserback button does not work

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

for our application we need deeplinking, however cant seem to implement a brwoser wide consistent working.Implemented it like this:

```
browserManager = BrowserManager.getInstance();
browserManager.init();
browserManager.addEventListener(BrowserChangeEvent.BROWSER_URL_CHANGE,parseUrl);
```

However the parseUrl function doesnt get called in every browser. IE seems to do, however.. the rest dont.. This should be working out of the box right?

Anybody has an idea on this?